# Getting HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR while querying the table created in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am getting the below error while querying the table created in Amazon Athena.

**Error**

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2

The sample file which I am using and the query to create table is below. The table gets successfully created by the below query but when I am fetching the result from table I am getting the error. Please provide your valuable suggestion.

**Note** [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDNQp.jpg)
         [Create table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bws13.jpg)

Answer (score 19):

AWS Athena does not support multi-line JSON.

[Athena knowledge center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-json-athena/)

> Make sure your JSON record is on a single line
>
> Athena doesn't currently support multi-line JSON records.

Comment: Thanks jens, but I amazon website it is depicted to cater multiline json file and also the table creation syntax is mentioned for the same. I have attached the both in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm abusing the answer field to have more space and to have my thoughts on this a little bit structured. I hope this is useful input to anyone using Athena.

I'm using Athena to create two tables. Single-line-json-based and multi-line-json-based reports in two separate bucket folders and two according tables.

Single-line reports in JSON are straightforward. For table creation I use this driver:

```
ROW FORMAT serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
```

However if you use this exact one to consume multi-line you will get an error PLUS there are three more things (**I**, **II** and **III**) to be aware of. First of all the different driver:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

then

**I** the (invalid) JSON format. My multi-line files look like this:

```
{"key": "value"}
{"key": "value"}
```

Notice there is one JSON object per line and objects are **NOT** comma separated!
You can read about this here:

[Store multiple elements in json files in AWS Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034094/store-multiple-elements-in-json-files-in-aws-athena/42035498)

**II** Create Statement

Contrary to your screenshot for table creation @abc I used it without nested structs:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS internal_reports (
`Date` Date,
impressions INT,
reach INT,
follower INT,
...
)
```

**III** Date property

I came across this whole driver-experimenting thing because the Date property caused issues in my single-line table because my values for Date had time information not equal to midnight. For the other multi-line reports my Dates were ok (the time was exactly midnight). You can read about this here:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/177238/timestamp-format-must-be-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmssffffffff/
[Athena - DATE column correct values from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139525/athena-date-column-correct-values-from-json)

Cheers