# Athena - Creating a Dynamic JSON Column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm in a bit of a dilemna here:

I'm using AWS Athena to query against some JSON objects. Most of the JSON records are structured, but one field in particular ("changes") has dynamic objects whose fields don't really have a set structure. For example, here's a record:

```
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 2,
    changes: {
    "customer_id" 1,
    "business_name: ['old name', 'new name']
    }
}
```

Every record has different keys and the value types vary. How can I represent this data? I thought maybe a string, but when I try to store it that way I get JSON parsing errors when decoding. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was actually misleading. The issue was that the S3 file it was trying to query over was an array of JSON objects. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034094/store-multiple-elements-in-json-files-in-aws-athena) question actually resolves the issue!